# Weird usage of && outside of a if?

Tags: javascript

Let's say we have this function:

```
loadView : function(view) {
    this.view && this.view.remove();
    this.view = view;
}
```

What does the first line do? For example if the line was this.view && this.otherView, it would return true if both view and otherView exists and false if one of them doesn't, but now there is a function being called at the end, which is confusing me.

Is the first line equivalent to:

```
if(this.view) {this.view.remove()}
```

?

Comment: Yes, the first line is equivalent to the `if` statement you posted - it's just a shorter version. It uses short-circuiting, as you've already pointed out (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-Circuit_Evaluation) - it only checks (executes) the second operand (the method call) if the first is truthy

Comment: Note: "*it would return true*" JavaScript's logical operators, `&&` and `||`, don't strictly return booleans. They return one of the 2 operands given to them after just testing the *truthiness* of the 1st.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's a [short circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

If `this.view` is ["falsey"](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/truthy-falsey/) then `this.view.remove()` will not be evaluated.

So the answer to your question is yes.

Comment: Not "false", but "falsey"

Comment: @Ian Thanks, I have update my answer with a link to a post about "falsey"

Answer (score 1):

It's called a guard operator. You would usually use && in this way

```
if(thing1 === 1 && thing2 === 2){}
```

You'll notice we want to check if BOTH things return true. Well the way it works is that we know that 'thing 2 === 0' will never run if the first expression (thing1 === 1) doesn't evaluate to true. Why run the second expression if they both have to be true and the first one already failed. Taking that knowledge we can now use it as a guard to not run the second expression, unless the first expression it true, or in this case truthy.

So in your code, this.view.remove() only runs if this.view is truthy.